# OMP more threads Than cores still same performance

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

i have a part of serial programm with OpenMP. When i excecute it with 8 threads (my computer can use 8 threads ) makes the same time when i excecute it with 16 or 32 or 64 etc. Is that normal? Couse i thought when i create more threads than cores the programm will be slowly. This is the code if you want to check it. It runs right! in the main,which is in other file, there is the set num of threads.

```
       void truncated_radix_sort(unsigned long int *morton_codes,
          unsigned long int *sorted_morton_codes,
          unsigned int *permutation_vector,
          unsigned int *index,
          int *level_record,
          int N,
          int population_threshold,
          int sft, int lv){

int BinSizes[MAXBINS] = {0};
unsigned int *tmp_ptr;
unsigned long int *tmp_code;

//thread management
extern int NUM_THREADS;
extern int activeThreads;
int startNewThreads = 0;
//if there's space for new threads, set flag to 1 and add the new threads to the count
//once calling is over, decrement count

level_record[0] = lv; // record the level of the node

if(N<=population_threshold || sft < 0) { // Base case. The node is a leaf
    memcpy(permutation_vector, index, N*sizeof(unsigned int)); // Copy the pernutation vector
    memcpy(sorted_morton_codes, morton_codes, N*sizeof(unsigned long int)); // Copy the Morton codes

    return;
}
else{

    // Find which child each point belongs to
    int j = 0;
    for(j=0; j<N; j++){
        unsigned int ii = (morton_codes[j]>>sft) & 0x07;
        BinSizes[ii]++;
    }


    // scan prefix (must change this code)
    int offset = 0, i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<MAXBINS; i++){
        int ss = BinSizes[i];
        BinSizes[i] = offset;
        offset += ss;
    }

    for(j=0; j<N; j++){
        unsigned int ii = (morton_codes[j]>>sft) & 0x07;
        permutation_vector[BinSizes[ii]] = index[j];
        sorted_morton_codes[BinSizes[ii]] = morton_codes[j];
        BinSizes[ii]++;
    }

    //swap the index pointers
    swap(&index, &permutation_vector);

    //swap the code pointers
    swap_long(&morton_codes, &sorted_morton_codes);
    int offsets[MAXBINS];
    offset = 0;
    offsets[0] = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<MAXBINS-1; i++) {
        int size = BinSizes[i] - offset;
        offset +=size;
        offsets[i+1] = offset;
    }

    #pragma omp flush(activeThreads)
    //Allow creation of new threads? Only if the number has not been exceeded
    if (activeThreads < NUM_THREADS && 0 == startNewThreads){
        startNewThreads = 1; //allow creation of more threads
    }
    if (activeThreads > NUM_THREADS && 1 == startNewThreads){
        startNewThreads = 0; //stop creating more threads
    }


    #pragma omp flush(startNewThreads)
    omp_set_nested(startNewThreads);
    /* Call the function recursively to split the lower levels */
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
    {
        #pragma omp for private(i) nowait\
        schedule(static)
        for(i=0; i<MAXBINS; i++){
            if (omp_get_nested()){
                #pragma omp atomic
                activeThreads ++; //account for new thread
                #pragma omp flush(activeThreads)
            }
            truncated_radix_sort(&morton_codes[offsets[i]],
                    &sorted_morton_codes[offsets[i]],
                    &permutation_vector[offsets[i]],
                    &index[offsets[i]], &level_record[offsets[i]],
                    sizes[i],
                    population_threshold,
                    sft-3, lv+1);
            if(omp_get_nested()){
                #pragma omp atomic
                activeThreads--;  //thread about to terminate
                #pragma omp flush(activeThreads)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: [this article](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/multi-core-and-multi-threading/) may help you understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your experiment is consitent with theory. You may want to read about [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law). Basically, according to this law you will have approximately the same performance as for the lower count of threads. In a real life it will start to decrease at some point (where you have too many threads). You may observe that if you have thousands of threads.